# Problem with aliased coefficients in using the mma package for multiple mediation

Tags: mediator

In my first step of the analysis using the data.org function, I received the error message below.

```
Error in Anova.III.LR.glm(mod, singular.ok = singular.ok) : 
  there are aliased coefficients in the model
```

I've tried to use either column number or variable names in the codes (see below), but both of them showed me the same error message. I've taken the codes from the paper "mma: An R Package for Mediation Analysis with Multiple Mediators". I've also read the codes from this website https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mma/vignettes/MMAvignette.html. I think my codes should be correct?   Can anyone please advise how I can solve the error and proceed to other analysis of the mma package? E.g., would the error be due to the missing values in my dataset, or the skewed distribution of the outcome variable?

```
# The predictor variables are: ECR_anxiety_average
pred <- alldata3[,c("ECR_anxiety_average")]

# The mediators are IRQ_original_total, IRQ_partner_total, CEER_total, IRIS_total, DERS_total
x <- alldata3[,c("IRQ_original_total", "IRQ_partner_total", "CEER_total", "IRIS_total", "DERS_total")]

# y is the outcome variable (CTS2 psy perpetration)
# The outcome variables for perpetration include: CTS2_psy_perp_total

y <- alldata3[,c("CTS2_psy_perp_total")]

data.step1 <- data.org(x,y,pred=372, contmed=c("IRQ_original_total", "IRQ_partner_total", "CEER_total", "IRIS_total", "DERS_total"), jointm=list(n=1,j1=c("IRQ_original_total", "IRQ_partner_total", "CEER_total", "IRIS_total")), alpha=0.4,alpha2=0.4)

data.step1 <- data.org(x,y,pred=pred, contmed=c(373:377), jointm=list(n=1,j1=c(373:376)), alpha=0.4,alpha2=0.4)
```